# Cloud function works locally, but not after deploying it

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am writing my very first Cloud Function which replaces the word "happy" with a smile.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.emojify = functions.database.ref("/messages/{pushId}/text").onWrite((change, context) => {
    const original = change.before.val();
    const emojified = emojifyText(original);

    return admin.database().ref().set(emojified);
});

function emojifyText(text) {
    let t = text;
    t = t.replace(/\b(H|h)appy\b/ig, "");

    console.log("Result:", t);

    return t;
};
```

I found out I can test before deploying by running `firebase functions:shell` and doing like this:

```
firebase > emojify({ before: "Happy!" })
'Successfully invoked function.'
firebase > info: User function triggered, starting execution
info: Result: !
info: Execution took 2949 ms, user function completed successfully
```

It works. However, when testing with my Android app, the logs of my function will show:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
    at emojifyText (/user_code/index.js:15:13)
    at exports.emojify.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:8:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
    at next (native)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
    at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:716:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

I don't understand.

After some new attempts, my code is the following:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.emojify = functions.database.ref("/messages/{pushId}/text").onWrite((change, context) => {
    // if (!change.before.val()) { return null; } 
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // I tried with this and without it, but neither helped.

    const original = change.after.val();
    const emojified = original.replace(/\b(H|h)appy\b/ig, "");

    return admin.database().ref("/messages/{pushId}/text").update(emojified);
});
```

The closest I got was to actually make it erase everything in the base, including the path `messages` and replace it with the written text, with the text replaced by the emoji. Something like:

[image]

But it was using `set()` instead of `update()`, which didn't show any sign of modifying anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const original = change.before.val();` is the data **before** the write. So if there was no data at the `"/messages/{pushId}/text"` node before you write there, the variable `original` will be null.

You shoud change to:

`const original = change.after.val();` which is the data **after** the write, i.e. your new data, which you want to "emojify".

---

**Update following your comments below**

You should use the `update()` method (doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#update)), as follows:

```
return admin.database().ref("/messages/" + context.params.pushId + "/").update({ text: emojified });
```

Comment: When doing so, it erased all the existing messages and even the `messages` path, replacing the `messages` path with the input text I wrote. At least the function did work.

Comment: I tried these and more, but all resulted in an error message or no error message but the update not applying. The error `First argument must be an object containing the children to replace`.  I'm going to update my question for you to see how's it now.

Comment: Read in detail how update() works, please. You should create an object with key/value pair and use it as the parameter.

Comment: @mfgabriel92 FYI, I've updated my answer with the way you should use the `update()` method.

Comment: I'm still having problems. I tried a lot with no success. The way you instructed me to do will actually create a child named "{pushId}". I then learned how to use `context` to retrieve the `pushId`, but then, the texts replaced are empty and I have this error `original.replace is not a function`. I don't know what to do, this is too difficult and annoying.

Comment: @mfgabriel92 There was a mistake in my last update, sorry. It should be `return admin.database().ref("/messages/" + context.params.pushId + "/text").update({emojified: emojified});` and not ref("/messages/{pushId}/text")!!

Comment: I figured it out, but then I will have this error: `original.replace is not a function`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172257/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-mfgabriel92).

Comment: Thank you a lot, my friend!